# Content-Type: application/json doesn't working with any eloquent beside all()

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get data with condition value and showing the result in json page, but the content-type doesn't working.

```
class ApidataController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $data = [];
        $data = Apidata::select('file')->where('nim','=',$request->nim)->get();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

[image: get() json page]

And when I'm trying to get all the data it does work:

```
class ApidataController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $data = [];
        $data = Apidata::all();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

[image: all() json page]

What should I do to make the get() json page to look like the all() json page?

Comment: Ditch the `header`, use `return response()->json($data);`. I think even `return $data` would return JSON. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses

Comment: This looks more like an issue with whatever browser extension it is you're using rather than laravel, but yes, as @kerbholz mentioned, the suggested way to output JSON is using `return response()->json($data);`